# Сохранение сцены перед переходом на следующую

Tags: javafx, java

Проблема состоит в том, что не сохраняется состояние задизейбленных (disabled) кнопок.

Предположим, что у нас есть две сцены: А и Б. На сцене А есть грид, состоящий из кнопок.
После нажатия на кнопку в соотв. обработчике она дизейблится, текущая сцена переустанавливается в Application.setScene() и загружается сцена Б. На сцене Б я вызываю
контроллер сцены А и изменяю содержимое Label-а.
ОК, это работает, но на загруженной сцене уже отсутствует состояние disabled кнопки! (сама кнопка присутствует : )). И я не понимаю, почему, ведь сцену-то я сохранил. Я уже не понимаю, куда смотреть, т.к. в офф. доках такие вопросы вообще не рассмотрены (как банально создать и забить программно/файлово сцену, я догоняю, но не более).

Код обработчика я уже выкладывал:

```
public void mouseClickedOnButtonHandler() {
    for (final Button button_for_handle : getButtons()) {
        button_for_handle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                Player.getPlayer(0).setScore(button_for_handle.getText());
                button_for_handle.setDisable(true);
                GameApp.currentStage.setScene(button_for_handle.getScene());
                loadScene("/view/file.fxml");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, правильно понял Ваш вопрос. У каждого контроллера сцены есть метод initialize, который запускается до того, как сцена "отрисуется".

```
@FXML
Button myDisabledButton;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
 //Почему бы Вам не поставить setDisable для кнопок здесь?
 myDisabledButton.setDisable(true);
}
```

После этих несложных манипуляций Ваши кнопку будут автоматически Disabled при загрузке данной сцены.

P.S.: Не забудьте внутри FXML файла для своих кнопок прописать их fx:id, чтобы обращаться к ним из контроллера:

```
<Button id="myCSSID" fx:id="myDisabledButton">
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что когда возвращаешься со сцены Б на сцену А эту кнопку я как будто бы и не нажимал, т.е. её состояние не сохраняется. Задумка была, чтобы пользователь больше не смог нажать на эту кнопку. Проблему я, в общем-то, уже решил, но извратиться пришлось неслабо - я просто сделал массив ID-шек нажатых кнопок и перед нажатием на любую из кнопок проверял, есть ли уже такая кнопка с заданным ID на сцене. Если сделать так, как Вы написали, то кнопка всегда будет disabled = ))) или я Вас не так понял ).

Comment: Нажатые кнопки не сохраняются в связи с тем, что FXML фаил не сохраняется после принудительного вызова button.setDisabled(true) на сцене (я предполагал обратное). Я посчитал крайне аморальным прописывать каждую из 25-и кнопок в контроллере = ))))).

Comment: Да, конечно, всегда disable будут, я не совсем развернуто написал. Так-то Вам, видимо, нужно где-то сохранять состояния кнопок дополнительно и в блоке inititalize загружать их и в зависимости от сохраненных настроек состояний организовывать сцену. Я использую легковесную бд H2, но у меня всегда бывает много настроек. Впрочем, если настроек мало можно и просто создать *.cfg какой-нибудь.

Конечно, если так много кнопок, то лучше их в реал-тайм создавать из массива или List, как удобнее.